# Code to abbreviate words longer than 10 characters not running properly

Tags: c++, arrays, string, c++17

This abbreviation is made like this: we write down the first and the last letter of a word and between them we write the number of letters between the first and the last letters. That number is in decimal system and doesn't contain any leading zeroes.

Thus, "localization" will be spelt as "l10n", and "internationalization" will be spelt as "i18n".

This is my code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int n,c;
    std::string str;
    c=0;
    char word[n][100];
    cin>>n;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        cin>>word[i];
    }
    for(int j=0;j<n;++j)
    {
        str = word[j];
        c = str.length();
        if(c>10)
            cout<<str[0]<<c-2<<str.back();
        else
            cout<<word[j]<<"\n";
        c=0;
    }
}
```

Can someone tell me what I should be changing?

Comment: Even with non-standard extensions, you need to create array *after* you read the size of that array, not before.

Comment: Unrelated: Since you know about `std::string`, why are you storing your words as `char[100]`? Also, why store words at all? You can just process words as they come in.

Comment: I'll be honest I'm not sure what std::string does I saw it on some other code and tried to implement it. As for storing the words, I need to get the output for all the words entering after entering all of them and not one-by-one.

Comment: Separate the different concern, in particular, you might create a function `std::string abbreviation(const std::string&)` in isolation.

Comment: `char word[n][100];` -- This is not valid C++.  Second:  *I'll be honest I'm not sure what std::string does I saw it on some other code and tried to implement it.* -- C++ is one of the most complex computer languages to learn.  You cannot learn it properly using the approach you're using.  Use good, peer-reviewed books and periodicals, not trial and error, seat-of-the-pants, picking up some code off the Internet, style of learning.  That may work with easy scripting languages, but it won't work for C++.

Answer (score 1):

We are here to help. OK, the task is understood. Now to your question:

> Can someone tell me what I should be changing?

First of all, the program does not compile on my machine, because of non-compliant language constructs like the VLA (variable length array). This is not legal C++ code. Then there is one major bug, where you use a non-initialized variable `n` to set the dimension for your (also forbidden) VLA. This will result in undefined behavior or a crash during runtime.

By the way, if you enable all warnings for your compiler, e.g. -wall -pedantic, then the compiler will find all the problems for you. Let us list up some more problems here.

- You should not use C-Functions and not include C-Headers like “stdlib.h”
- Do not use `using namespace std;`. Always use fully qualified names
- Always initialize all variables while defining them
- Use meaningful, descriptive variable names, not one letter names like n, c
- Do not use C-Style arrays in C++. Use `std::array` or here better `std::vector` instead. There is no reason whatsoever to use C-Style arrays.
- You know `std::string`, because you use it. So, then please consequently use `std::string` for strings. Never use old C-Style strings with `char[]` or `char*`
- The last statement `c=0;` is not needed. `c` will be overwritten anyway by `strlen` in the next round.
- For the size of your words you use the magic number 100. Magic Numbers should not be used. What, if the user enters a string with more the 100 characters. A disaster will happen. If at all, then please use `cin.get` in that case. But best is to use a `std::string`.

Ok, with the above wisdom, let us do the first refactoring step. We will keep your programming style, but must replace the VLA with dynamic memory management using new and raw pointers. Please note: New and raw pointer must not be used for owned memory in C++. Anyway. For the first step, we will use it. And, of course we will use `std::string` for strings.

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int n,c;
    std::string str;
    c=0;
    cin>>n;
    std::string* word = new std::string[n];
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        cin>>word[i];
    }
    for(int j=0;j<n;++j)
    {
        str = word[j];
        c = str.length();
        if(c>10)
            cout<<str[0]<<c-2<<str.back() << "\n";
        else
            cout<<word[j]<<"\n";
        c=0;
    }
    delete[] word;
}
```

Next step. Remove unnecessary stuff. Uses meaningful variable names and comments.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>

// Program to create abbreviations for words

// This abbreviation is made like this: we write down the first and the last letter
// of a word and between them we write the number of letters between the first and 
// the last letters. That number is in decimal system and doesn't contain any leading 
// zeroes.

// Thus, "localization" will be spelt as "l10n", and "internationalization" will be 
// spelt as "i18n".

// Words above this length will be transformed
constexpr unsigned int MaxWordLength = 10u;

int main()
{
    // We will get the numberOfWords from the user and check for a valid input
    unsigned int numberOfWords{};
    if ((std::cin >> numberOfWords) and (numberOfWords > 0)) {
        
        // Here we will store all words read from the user
        std::string* words = new std::string[numberOfWords]{};
        
        // Now read the specified amount of words from user
        for(unsigned int index=0; index<numberOfWords; ++index)  {
            std::cin >> words[index];
        }
        
        // Abbreviation activity
        for(unsigned int index=0; index<numberOfWords; ++index) {
            
            // Check length of word
            const std::string& word = words[index];
            const unsigned int wordLength = word.length();
            
            // If word is longer than threshold, do abbreviation
            if(wordLength > MaxWordLength)
            
                // Print abbreviated word
                std::cout << word[0] << wordLength-2 << word.back() << '\n';
            else
                // Print word as is
                std::cout << word << '\n';
        }
        delete[] words;
    }
    else std::cerr << "\nError: Invalid input\n\n";
}
```

Next, lets get rid of `new` and use a `std::vector`. This will not affect the whole program. It is equivalent. But we will use some more improvements like range based for loops.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

// Program to create abbreviations for words

// This abbreviation is made like this: we write down the first and the last letter
// of a word and between them we write the number of letters between the first and 
// the last letters. That number is in decimal system and doesn't contain any leading 
// zeroes.

// Thus, "localization" will be spelt as "l10n", and "internationalization" will be 
// spelt as "i18n".

// Words above this length will be transformed
constexpr size_t MaxWordLength = 10u;

int main()
{
    // We will get the numberOfWords from the user and check for a valid input
    size_t numberOfWords{};
    if ((std::cin >> numberOfWords) and (numberOfWords > 0)) {
        
        // Here we will store all words read from the user
        std::vector<std::string> words(numberOfWords);
        
        // Now read the specified amount of words from user
        for(std::string& word : words)  {
            std::cin >> word;
        }
        
        // Abbreviation activity
        for(std::string& word : words) {
            
            // Check length of word
            const size_t wordLength = word.length();
            
            // If word is longer than threshold, do abbreviation
            if(wordLength > MaxWordLength)
            
                // Print abbreviated word
                std::cout << word[0] << wordLength - 2u << word.back() << '\n';
            else
                // Print word as is
                std::cout << word << '\n';
        }
    }
    else std::cerr << "\nError: Invalid input\n\n";
}
```

This is now already rather good.

I you want to see the more advanced C++ solution, you may check the below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
// Program to create abbreviations for words

// This abbreviation is made like this: we write down the first and the last letter
// of a word and between them we write the number of letters between the first and 
// the last letters. That number is in decimal system and doesn't contain any leading 
// zeroes.

// Thus, "localization" will be spelt as "l10n", and "internationalization" will be 
// spelt as "i18n".

// Words above this length will be transformed
constexpr size_t MaxWordLength = 10u;

int main()
{
    // We will get the numberOfWords from the user and check for a valid input
    if (size_t numberOfWords; (std::cin >> numberOfWords) and (numberOfWords > 0)) {
        
        // Here we will store all words read from the user
        std::vector<std::string> words(numberOfWords);
        
        // Now read the specified amount of words from user
        std::copy_n(std::istream_iterator<std::string>(std::cin), numberOfWords, words.begin());
        
        // Abbreviation activity and output
        std::transform(words.begin(), words.end(), std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(std::cout,"\n"), [](const std::string& w){
            return (w.length() > MaxWordLength) ? (w[0]+std::to_string(w.length()-2)+w.back()) : w;});
    }
    else std::cerr << "\nError: Invalid input\n\n";
}
```